# How can I send cookies with Perl's LWP::Simple?

Tags: perl, http, cookies, lwp

```
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;
use Data::Dumper;
#my $url = shift @ARGV;
my $content = get('example.com?GET=whateverIwant');
my $parser = HTML::LinkExtor->new(); #create LinkExtor object with no callbacks
$parser->parse($content); #parse content
```

now if I want to send POST and COOKIE info as well with the HTTP header how can I configure that with the get funciton? or do I have to customize my own method?

My main interest is Cookies! then Post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple) is for very simple HTTP GET requests.  If you need to do anything more complex (like cookies), you have to upgrade to a full [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent).  The `cookie_jar` is a [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aCookies) object, and you can use its `set_cookie` method to add a cookie.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(cookie_jar => {}); # create an empty cookie jar

$ua->cookie_jar->set_cookie(...);

my $rsp = $ua->get('example.com?GET=whateverIwant');
die $rsp->status_line unless $rsp->is_success;
my $content = $rsp->decoded_content;
...
```

The LWP::UserAgent also has a `post` method.

Comment: But what are the arguments to set_cookie! The documentation refers to $version, but doesn't give any details! http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Cookies-6.01/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm#METHODS

Comment: @Chloe, it expects you to be familiar with the cookie spec.  See [RFC 2965](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) instead. It already glues together most of the stuff that you want:

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;
 
 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

 $mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie(...);

 $mech->get( ... );

 my @links = $mech->links;
```

Comment: You don't need `cookie_jar => {}` here, because WWW::Mechanize already defaults to that (unlike its base class, LWP::UserAgent, which does not create a cookie_jar unless requested to).

Comment: Heh, I can never remember which way it goes. :)